# Same Bin file to similar ESP32 boards yields different results

Tags: esp32, firmware

Sorry for the confusing title. It is a bit hard to explain.

We have a remote developer who compiles his code into a bin file and sends it to all of us. He loads it onto his ESP32 boards and they work just fine. However, when we load the bin file onto our ESP32 boards, they do not work. We are all using the same configuration ESP32 boards. We are all using Expressif Flash Download tool to load the bin file.

Where would y'all recommend I start my investigation? What additional info do you need from me to help figure this out? I have confirmed that we are all using the same ESP32 boards as well as the same flash tool. Ideas?

By the way, I am not the programmer, I do not have access to the source code. I only have the bin file.

Thank you

Comment: how is the bin file created?

Comment: start by sending one of your boards to the developer for testing

Comment: @jsotola I can do that. Good call. I'll let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. I hadn't wired the final product exactly as the designer had. Once the wiring was correct the issue was resolved. Just needed a physical troubleshooting as the software troubleshooting wasn't the issue.

Funny thing is, there are only two wires on the entire project and I had gotten them wrong.

So I think the lesson here is, check your physical configuration as well as the software/firmware.

Thank you all for your help.